# syntax to access http response - type Observable<Response> is missing following propertie

Tags: angular

I have below angular code working correctly:

```
return this.http.get('my_url')
    .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
    }
);
```

Now I want to re-write it to multiple lines like this:

```
let response: Response;
response = this.http.get('my_url'); // error in this line.
return response.json();
```

But I get error as `type Observable<Response> is missing following properties from type 'Response'` .

What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: What Angular version are you using..?

Answer (score -1):

try `async / await`

e.g.

#### Promise

```
async getResponse() {
   const response = await this.http.get('my_url').toPromise();
   return response.json();
}
```

#### Observable

Angular's this.http.get returns an RxJS Observable. Then calling this.http.get(...).subscribe(...) returns RxJS Subscription object.

> When working with an Observable, you would use the subscribe() method
> for getting data. When you subscribe, the callback that you provide to
> the subscribe() method will be executed once or multiple times
> whenever there is some new data. But when you convert the Observable
> to a promise, the callback provided to the then() method is executed
> one time no more. If you don't need to observe a source for a stream
> of data that comes in different points of time, you can use promises
> instead of Observables which need to be unsubscribed or otherwise will
> cause memory leaks and unexpected behaviors if not handled right.

https://www.techiediaries.com/javascript-async-await-tutorial/

Comment: I want to use observable in my code rather than promise, how can I do that